# DB structure/file formats to persist a 100TB table and support efficient data skipping with predicates in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, filter, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, parquet

I'm optimizing a Spark SQL ETL to frequently select 0.1% of data from a 100 billion rows, 100TB parquet formatted table 'event_100B' on S3.

Table event_100B contains a unique key column EventId (32 hex uuid). The select query needs to be optimized is joining a predicate_set providing 100 mil EventId keys as predicate, which map to randomly distributed rows in the event table. No clustering pattern can be exploited.

```
select t1.* from event_100B t1
inner join predicate_set p1 on t1.EventId = p1.EventId
```

Because the predicate consists of a bag of high cardinality keys spanning a large min-max range, neither file nor row-group level pruning takes place. The ETL spends a significant % time downloading files to run full table scan.

Looking for advice what DB or file formats can support effective data skipping with this type of bulk random access query, and if necessary the kind of AWS/Azure storage hardware.

A Tentative Idea:
Assign all EventIds into 100 mil buckets: BucketId = EventId % 1,000,000 such that each bucket contains avg 1000 EventId values. The event_100B is then clustered/sorted table rows by BucketId.

The BucketId column requires much less IO & network bandwidth to download and join with the predicate_set:

```
select t1.* from event_100B t1
inner join predicate_set p1 on t1.BucketId = (p1.EventId % 1,000,000)
```

My expectation: by increasing the bucket count, the probability of any predicate EventId falls into a bucket decreases and a higher % of buckets (and associated rows) can be skipped.

Comment: What about creating parquet bloom indexes on eventId, and turning the join into a in statement ? Maybe 100k predicate could be turned into small batches

Comment: You could also create a side table with a row per parquet file, and an array of eventid contained within. Then a first query would tell you the subset of parquet files to read, and could save a lot of io for the second qury on the main table.

Comment: If either approach is of interest just tell me I would write a detaikked answer

Comment: Side table is good idea! i think that’s the right direction - plain parquet does not have sufficient metadata to support ‘100 mil needles in 100B haystacks’. I need to experiment a gigantic index structure to realize seeking a random 1% rows, backed by a capable storage infra. If all goes well, the end latency should show visible improvement over sequential scanning of 100% rows

Comment: Also looking for recommendations on distributed columnar DB suitable for the use case, as a substitution for parquet.

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a clustered index, something that has existed for decades, but just doesn't exist in data lakes

Comment: You sound like an expert so this is a question from me: Doesn't partitioning already do this for you? If you partition on EventId and every partition (file) has a known min/max value for eventid, doesn't that support automatic file pruning?

Answer (score 0):

100TB of parquet files easily represents million of files. As a result the query engine will spend lot of time getting footers and worst in your context scan the data of most files.

One approach to limit the number of parquet files to read, is to maintain a side index telling you for each parquet files, the list of eventid they contains. Of course you can keep parquet to build this index because it's a matter of few million rows in worst case. Then knowing which files contains your 100k events should be fairly fast, and hopefully you would then end up reducing the parquet files to be read.

You could have a more simple design by trying out other technologies such as starrocks/apache Doris. They are great candidate for your use case because they provide a native format compatible with object storage/hdfs with statistics, indexing, cost based optimizers the c++ engine is highly vectorized. BTW I wouldn't consider Trino(parquet), clickhouse(poor join support),  or elasticsearch(bad for retriving lot of records).

Lastly you could also consider tables format based on parquet. With [apache hudi](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/indexing/) you could for example build a bloom filter index on eventid, and store it in the metadata table. While designed to faster uptates, the index can also be used for read queries by using rdd api. Also [apache iceberg has ongoing work](https://iceberg.apache.org/puffin-spec/) to provide built-in indexing capabilities but so far it's not yet mature enough AFAIK.

Let us know your final conclusions !

Comment: Not trolling or anything but I just find it frustrating with datalake architectures that we spend so much time manully reinventing technologies that have been around for decades, in this example, this is similiar to a non clustered index.

Comment: thanks for your remark, added some thougth about table format with builtin indexes